# What is Processing Strategy in Mule ESB

Tags: mule-esb

Please provide my brief description on Processing strategy in mule. That topic is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Mule 3.

Here's the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/flow-processing-strategies

Mule 4 (supposedly): https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/96610/mule-4-processing-strategies.html